# Comparing computed dates with entered dates

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, comparison, worksheet-function

I have in cell p4 the date:
`2014-01-01` (obtained via formula (`=(((O5/1000/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1))`)

I have in cell b5 the date:
`2014-01-01` (typed in)

`=(p4=b5)` gives false

`=(p4>=b5)` gives false

How do I compare dates correctly in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be safe with chopping the parts up and reassembling them:

```
=DATE(YEAR(P4),MONTH(P4),DAY(P4))=DATE(YEAR(B5),MONTH(B5),DAY(B5))
```

Comment: "easier to read".. Uh, really? For a human, knowing that we're offsetting from that date and why we're dividing by what we're dividing seems to make more sense. Maybe you meant that it would save Excel computation time?

Comment: To each his own, I guess. True, but I'm using 1/1/1970 b/c that's unix timestamp (most likely won't change that date). Also, I don't care to prettify this excel sheet, just trying to quickly get things done :)

Comment: I too would use `DATE(1970,1,1)` - more transparent but also it works with either date system - 25569 wouldn't be correct using 1904 date system

Answer (score 0):

- Select the two date cells.
- Press CTRL+1 to show the format tab
- On the Number tab, in the Format list, click Text

Perhaps there is a more appropriate comparison format, when you have dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD I think this one will work).

Comment: Ok, doing this gave me some insight into the problem. The computed date is not exactly 2014-01-01; it was merely showing that b/c of my formatting. How can I make the cell actually contain 2014-01-01:00:00:00 instead of some time offset?

Comment: Press `CTRL+1` and select the Date tab and pick an appropriate format.

Comment: For this answerer, the format you suggest is what I had it in originally. Problem is, even though Excel displays that format, it still internally maintains the actual date time (doesn't actually round date time to date). @pnuts That was it. That will round down the decimal value Excel stores for date time to an int, representing 00:00:00 time at that date. Thanks