# Excel difference between two dates not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my issue :

```
A1 :02/01/2018
formula : "=A1 - (2/1/2018)"
result  43101,99901
```

How can I make the formula retrieve 0?

Thank you

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278811/date-comparison-not-working-in-excel-formula/26278992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Date` in quotes:

```
=A1-"02/01/2018"
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i tried to simplify the issue but missed the point. the technic doesn't work in VBA. The value "2/1/2018" is actually given by "Dim exportDate  as Date" , when I do `A1 - " & exportDate & "` it results in this formula in the workbook `A1- 2/1/2018`, and this `A1 - "" & exportDate & ""` results in `A1 - " & exportDate & "` which retrieves `#VALUE!`. How to solve this issue? thank you

Comment: Then you need to ask a new question that states the use of vba and show the vba you have tried.

Comment: I tried doing it but I can only post one question each 90min and I finish work in 1 hour, I would love to find an issue to this problem because it is driving me crazy. I can change de subject of the question to match. is it ok?

Comment: No if you change the question then my answer no longer is valid and will open me up for down-votes. @Takichiii

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `DATE` function.

```
= A1-DATE(2018,2,1)
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, could this work?

```
= A1-DATEVALUE("02/01/2018")
```

Comment: thanks, but this function is too hard to use when fetching data (from the filename for eg which was the case here)

Comment: See my answer, I edited again to show another possible solution. Does this work?