# Google Sheets - IF Statement - Null date (1/1/2500) workaround

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets

I am working on a large nested IF statement that checks several validation points for each row of my sheet. There are several date validations, including chronological order and certain fields not being future dates. However, our system requires that if we must null any dates for processing, that date becomes 1/1/2500, and no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the formula to ignore this date when accounting for future dates or chronology.

```
//The date cannot be later than the current date - I want this to ignore 1/1/2500
IF(K1<>1/1/2500,"",IF(AND(K1>TODAY()),"Date A cannot be future date",""))

//The two dates must be in chronological order, also ignoring 1/1/2500
IF(U1<>1/1/2500,"",IF(AND(U1>AA1,AA1),"Date A, Date B should be in chronological order",""))
```

The above approach does not seem to recognize 1/1/2500, even though I got it to work with other dates.
I also tried going with `>12/31/2099` (ignore any date greater than 12/31/2099) but it just ignores every date.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it is failing because K1 is compared to 12/31/2099.

If you use an expression like this in a formula, it will interpret it as an arithmetic expression 12 divided by 31 divided by 2099, which is a very small number, so the greater than test will always be true.

Try starting the formula with [Date](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en) to convert a year, month, and day into a date.

```
If(K1>date(2099,12,31)
```

and you should get the right answer.

[See my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278811/date-comparison-not-working-in-excel-formula) for Excel.