# Excel IF AND statement returning false when true

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a formula that is supposed to check if two statements are true: that the name shows up corresponding with a certain date. If true return the word YES, and if false return the word NO.

For some reason the formula provides the correct answer in some cases and the wrong answer in others and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

The statement is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(Transfers!$A$2:$A$500=$B$2,Transfers!$B$2:$B$500=A3),"Yes","No")
```

`Transfers` is just the name of the tab where it's searching for the criteria.

For some reason some provide **YES** as it should and other provide **NO** when it should be **YES**. Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a copy of your sheet and put it on Google? - And share it of course. I'll take a look? :)

Comment: If you go to a cell that is returning the wrong result and step through it using the Evaluate Formula tool on the Formula tab of the Ribbon you will see where it's going wrong.

Comment: The evaluate formula in ribbon is telling me it's false but I can't see why it would be, I have uploaded an excel doc that includes the relevant sections of the sheet im working on (with names redacted since it's for work) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ycvI8xvdy7RL0PClLr1SQbCDoZx_7oCAHtYwg26YVo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your dates are really dates... see [this answer on bad formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278811/date-comparison-not-working-in-excel-formula).

If that's not it, just be careful when calculating dates... see [this answer on calculating dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943600/comparing-computed-dates-with-entered-dates).

I'd bet the latter.  Excel is very picky about exact matching like your trying to do ... As an extreme, you could google "fuzzy lookup", but I think that's overkill for your application.

Comment: I've double checked as dates have thrown me issues before but both areas that its checking dates are formatted as such and using the same date format. I have uploaded a version of what im working on with sensitive info removed if you wanted to take a look. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ycvI8xvdy7RL0PClLr1SQbCDoZx_7oCAHtYwg26YVo/edit#gid=1583725127

Comment: Ah, I see what your trying to do now.  You'll probably want `COUNTIFS`... I'll look into it.

Comment: You were right, replacing the and argument with COUNTIFS returned the right results. thanks again :)

Comment: Well, OK, beat me to it. Glad we could help. Btw, I just came up with this: `=COUNTIFS(Transfers!A:A,"="&B$2,Transfers!B:B,"="&$A3)>0`  Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but you get the idea.

Comment: The way I ended up writing it which still gave me the yes or no answer I was looking for was =IF(COUNTIFS(TransferDateRange,B2,TransferNameRange,$A$7),"Yes","No")